# How to get all objects of a choice field?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm doing a search form where an user selects the category and the type of product which is a choice field of the Product model, product_type = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=TYPE, default='Physical'). I can get the categories but not the choices in TYPE to add to the form.

choices.py

```
TYPE = [
    ('PHYSICAL', _('Physical')),
    ('DIGITAL', _('Digital')),
]
```

views.py

```
from .choices import TYPE

def is_valid_queryparam(param):
    return param != '' and param is not None

def FilterView(request):
    qs = Product.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    ptypes = Product.product_type.all()  # The problem line

    category = request.GET.get('category')
    ptype = request.GET.get('ptype')

    if is_valid_queryparam(category) and category != 'Choose...':
        qs = qs.filter(category__name=category)

    if is_valid_queryparam(ptype) and ptype != 'Choose...':
        qs = qs.filter(product_type=ptype)

    context = {
        'queryset': qs,
        'categories' : categories,
        'ptypes' : ptypes,
    }

    return render(request, 'categories/display_query.html', context)
```

base.html

```
    <div>
    <h3>Advanced Search</h3>
        <form method="GET" action="{% url 'filter-view' %}">
            <div>
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <select name="category">
                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                    {% for cat in categories %}
                    <option value="{{ cat }}">{{ cat }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="ptype">Product type</label>
                <select name="ptype">
                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                    {% for type in ptype %}
                    <option value="{{ type }}">{{ type }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

display_query.html

```
{% extends 'products/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <ul>
        {% for product in queryset %}
            <li>
                {{ product.title }}
                <span>Author: {{ product.author.username }}</span>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
     </ul>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the given code:

```
p_types_keys = [i[0] for i in TYPE]
p_types_values = [i[1] for i in TYPE]
ptype_dict = dict(zip(p_types_keys, p_types_values))
```

In the line will return all the keys of your "TYPE"
The second line will return all the keys of your "TYPE"
The Third line will return the key-value pair of your types to add form.

Comment: I replaced the line "ptypes = Product.product_type.all()" for that code and changed the context to be "'ptypes' : ptype_dict," and nothing appears.

Comment: When You are directly accessing ```Product.product_type``` that means you are accessing the "product_type" field of the "Product" table. It may raise an error. to get choices like your given way. You need to access choice values from that field. So you can try that ```ptypes = Product.product_type.field.choices```. Hope it will work for you.